# Security Structure of an API

Tags: tls, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, x.509

I've been developing a web application and APIs for 8 months. I implemented OAuth 2.0 client credentials for authentication. And now I have to implement TLS to my APIs.
I've been dealing with SSL/TLS security implementations for days. I couldn't anything. Still, I'm at the start and started to feel the despair.

I can be wrong, but I thought, I can issue certificates on my web page to my users. And users can use those when they are trying to use my API for SSL-Client Authentication. (like [Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/#renewing-an-api-certificate)) There are a lot of things that are must known. So I need help.

Q: I'd like to know is there any missing item on my list **?** What else should I do **?**
 Q: Would it be possible there is an alternate way to provide secure for my API **?**

Summary of my to-do list;

1. Create a CA key and cert using [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ca.html)
2. Create server key and cert using [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509.html)
3. Put a "new cert." button on my web page and code 
   If a user clicks the button then;

   a. generate a downloadable client certificate using [PKIjs-x509](https://github.com/GlobalSign/PKI.js/blob/master/examples/Create%20new%20X.509%20certificate/CreateNewX509Certificate.html#L224-L235)

   b. a copy of the certificate is saved on a `clients` folder on the server
4. Create and manage a Certificate Revocation List to CA using using [PKIjs-CRL](https://github.com/GlobalSign/PKI.js/tree/master/examples/CRL%20complex%20example)
5. Put a "remove cert." button on the web page and code 
   If a user clicks the button then;

   a. add related certificate to CRL
6. If a user leave from system then add related certificate to CRL

I think number 4, 5 and 6 (CRL operations) are redundant. I need a secure connection between client and server. Every different client certificate creates a different secure channel to the server. So, if a malicious man uses a certificate he can access only my authorization server, securely. Therefore these items seem not important *in my case*. Are they?

I use Node.js and javascript.
I found some useful javascript libraries like [PKIjs](https://github.com/GlobalSign/PKI.js/tree/master/examples), [forge.js](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) and [pem](https://github.com/andris9/pem) .

I've given a call to one of the global CA companies for their PKI service. They gave me $30 per client and I cannot use their CRL as programmaticaly on my application. This is impossible for me. So I've been trying to solve by myself.

Keywords to remember some things;
( EJBCA, x.509, PKI, Key-Exchange, S/MIME, OpenSSL, RSA, ASN.1, PCKS, Fingerprint )

Comment: Are you sure you need client certificates? You already have OAuth

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Because I've implemented client credential authentication.A client make a request for an `access token` to my authorization server using HTTP-Basic Authentication method that is included `client_id` and `client_secret` as username and password. And this communication should be occured in a secure channel. The specification indicates as TLS in many places. e.g. Section 2.3.1 Client Passowrd `The authorization server MUST require the use of TLS as described in Section 1.6 when sending requests using password authentication.` https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-2.3.1

Comment: at the same time **I guess**, someone can read a user's data-packages and take `access_token`. So developers who use OAuth 2.0 must use TLS at every single time.

Comment: I'm going to second Neil here. This sounds like you need a confidential channel to the server. And regular server-auth-but-no-client-auth type TLS will do that nicely. If you have a different method of authenticating the client, then you don't need to use TLS's way of doing this. (And I also don't see how the RFC mandates client side certs.)

Comment: I need every idea. Actually you're right. However, I think OAuth 2.0 might provide me some advantages on my mobile app in the future. And yes, RFC doesn't say that how to use TLS on auth operation, one-way or two-way (mutual). I'd really like to know if there is an alternate way you know :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution as I was looking for;

http://blog.engelke.com/2015/03/03/creating-x-509-certificates-with-web-crypto-and-pkijs/

But I'll try [pem](https://github.com/andris9/pem) modulus at first. Because it works on back-end and seems more simple.